# Unable to add data in Room using RxJava Completable

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am making an app using MVVM architecture pattern I am trying to use RxJava to add data in room database but it is showing red line under lambda expression saying

> Bad return type in lambda expression : void cannot be converted to Object.

Below is my code:

**UserDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

@Insert
void insert(User user);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id DESC")
Flowable<List<User>> getAllUsers();

}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public class UserRepository {

private UserDb userDb;
private UserDao userDao;
private Flowable<List<User>> allUsers;

public UserRepository(Application application) {

    userDb = UserDb.getInstance(application);
    userDao = userDb.userDao();
    allUsers = userDao.getAllUsers();
}

public void insert(final User user){

   Completable.fromCallable(() -> userDb.userDao().insert(user))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete() {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                }
                            });
    }
}
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Can u show the code for flowable for how you handled that query pls!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `Completable.fromCallable`, you should use `Completable.fromAction`, which doesn't need lambda to return something.

To show a toast when insertion completed or failed:

```
public class UserRepository {

private UserDb userDb;
private UserDao userDao;
private Flowable<List<User>> allUsers;

    public UserRepository(Application application) {

        userDb = UserDb.getInstance(application);
        userDao = userDb.userDao();
        allUsers = userDao.getAllUsers();
    }

    public Completable insert(final User user){

       return Completable.fromAction(() -> userDb.userDao().insert(user))
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

inside your activity:

```
    public void onInsertClicked(){
        userRepository = //get your repository instance.
        //remember to dispose this disposable when activity destroyed, otherwise the onComplete callback will leak reference to our activity.
        Disposable disposable = userRepository.subscribe(() -> Toast.makeText(this, "Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(), 
                throwable -> Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }
```

**If you don't want to call insert inside your activity:**

you can also save the reference to the Application inside your Repository

```
public class UserRepository {

    private UserDb userDb;
    private UserDao userDao;
    private Flowable<List<User>> allUsers;
    private final Context context;

    public UserRepository(Application application) {

        userDb = UserDb.getInstance(application);
        userDao = userDb.userDao();
        allUsers = userDao.getAllUsers();
        context = application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void insert(final User user){

       Completable.fromAction(() -> userDb.userDao().insert(user))
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(() -> Toast.makeText(context, "Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(), 
                                                throwable -> Toast.makeText(context, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }
}
```

Comment: One more thing how do I show success or error toast message after insertion.

Comment: Then you must have a reference to a context, I suggest your repository returns this Completable directly, and let downstream to handle `onComplete` or `onError`

Comment: To show a toast, you can use this line of code:`Toast.makeText(context, "insert completed! / error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: As I said, you must get this context reference by yourself, you can either pass context as an argument to this insert method or let downstream which has the reference to a context to subscribe this Completable.

Comment: Could you please show me in code as I am unable to get it.

Comment: I modified the answer, hope it helps. @Digvijay

Comment: Your answer still uses `fromCallable`, didn't you mean `fromAction`?

Comment: @akarnokd Oops, forgot to change that, thanks for pointing out.